# Manipulating the legend of scale_fill_gradient2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient

I have data which comes from a statistical test (gene set enrichment analysis, but that's not important), so I obtain p-values for statistics that are normally distributed, i.e., both positive and negative values:

The test is run on several categories:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(col = rep(1,7), 
                 category = LETTERS[1:7], 
                 stat.sign = sign(rnorm(7)), 
                 p.value = runif(7, 0, 1), 
                 stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

I want to present these data in a `geom_tile` `ggplot` such that I color code the `df$category` by their `df$p.value` multiplied by their `df$stat.sign` (i.e, the sign of the statistic)

For that I first take the `log10` of `df$p.value`:

```
df$sig <- df$stat.sign*(-1*log10(df$p.value))
```

Then I `order` the `df` by `df$sig` for each sign of `df$sig:`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- rbind(dplyr::filter(df, sig < 0)[order(dplyr::filter(df, sig < 0)$sig), ],
            dplyr::filter(df, sig > 0)[order(dplyr::filter(df, sig > 0)$sig), ])
```

And then I `ggplot` it:

```
library(ggplot2)
df$category <- factor(df$category, levels=df$category)

ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = col, y = category)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=sig)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low='darkblue', mid='white', high='darkred') + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  xlab("") + ylab("") + labs(fill="-log10(P-Value)") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold"), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

which gives me:

[image]

Is there a way to manipulate the `legend` such that the values of `df$sig` are represented by their absolute value but everything else remains unchanged? That way I still get both red and blue shades and maintain the order I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check ggplot's documentation, `scale_fill_gradient2`, like other continuous scales, accepts one of the following for its `labels` argument:

- `NULL` for no labels
- `waiver()` for the default labels computed for the transofrmation object
- a character vector giving labels (must be same length as `breaks`)
- **a function that takes the breaks as input and returns labels as output**

Since you only want the legend values to be absolute, I assume you're satisfied with the default breaks in the legend colour bar (-0.1 to 0.4 with increments in 0.1), so all you really need is to add a function that manipulates the labels.

I.e. instead of this:

```
scale_fill_gradient2(low = 'darkblue', mid = 'white', high = 'darkred') +
```

Use this:

```
scale_fill_gradient2(low = 'darkblue', mid = 'white', high = 'darkred',
                     labels = abs) +
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I did understood what you're looking for. Do you meant that you wan't to change the **labels** within legends? If you want to change labels manipulating `breaks` and `labels` given by `scale_fill_gradient2()` shall do it.

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=col,y=category)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=sig)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low='darkblue',mid='white',high='darkred',
                       breaks = order(unique(df$sig)),
                       labels = abs(order(unique(df$sig)))) +
  theme_minimal()+xlab("")+ylab("")+labs(fill="-log10(P-Value)") +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=12,face="bold"),axis.text.x=element_blank())
```

For what you're looking for maybe you could display texts inside the figure to show the values, try stacking `stat_bin_2d()` like this:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=col,y=category)) +
      geom_tile(aes(fill=sig)) +
      scale_fill_gradient2(low='darkblue',mid='white',high='darkred',
                           breaks = order(unique(df$sig)),
                           labels = abs(order(unique(df$sig)))) +
      theme_minimal()+xlab("")+ylab("")+labs(fill="-log10(P-Value)") +
      stat_bin_2d(geom = 'text', aes(label = sig), colour = 'black', size = 16) +
      theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=12,face="bold"),axis.text.x=element_blank())
```

You might want to give the `size` and `colour` arguments some tries.